# Maven Deploy to Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I want to deploy Maven based war file to Tomcat.
Technologies used :

Maven 3.1.1
Eclipse 4.2
JDK 7
Spring 4.1.1.RELEASED
Tomcat 7
Logback 1.0.13

I have this plugin in my maven file:

```
<!-- For Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path>/DevicesCloudWebApp</path>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>admin</password>
                <update>true</update>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

but when I deploy using the command `mvn tomcat7:deploy`

I have this error:

```
    [DEBUG] Connection 0.0.0.0:62265<->127.0.0.1:8080 closed
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) > package @ DevicesCloudWebApp >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ DevicesCloudWebApp ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ DevicesCloudWebApp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ DevicesCloudWebApp ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/nullpointer/Development/J2EE/eclipseWSJ2EE/DevicesCloudWebApp/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ DevicesCloudWebApp ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ DevicesCloudWebApp ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ DevicesCloudWebApp ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [DevicesCloudWebApp] in [/Users/nullpointer/Development/J2EE/eclipseWSJ2EE/DevicesCloudWebApp/target/DevicesCloudWebApp]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/Users/nullpointer/Development/J2EE/eclipseWSJ2EE/DevicesCloudWebApp/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [97 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /Users/nullpointer/Development/J2EE/eclipseWSJ2EE/DevicesCloudWebApp/target/DevicesCloudWebApp.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) < package @ DevicesCloudWebApp <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) @ DevicesCloudWebApp ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/DeviceslCloudWebApp  
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FDeviceslCloudWebApp
2170/6062 KB   
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Broken pipe
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FDeviceslCloudWebApp
2198/6062 KB   
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Broken pipe
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FDeviceslCloudWebApp
2176/6062 KB   
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Broken pipe
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FDeviceslCloudWebApp
2188/6062 KB   
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.922 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-02T20:57:29+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/303M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project DevicesCloudWebApp: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Broken pipe -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: We need to see further back in this error log. The error that caused it to not start up properly is there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding authentication configuration like below

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat7-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
            <server>tomcat</server>
            <username>admin1</username>
            <password>admin1</password>
            <path>/${project.artifactId}</path>
            <update>true</update>
         </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Update the role configuration like below in the tomcat -> `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml` in `<tomcat-users>` element

```
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin1" password="admin1" roles="manager-script"/>
```

Comment: 2082/25198 KB   
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
[INFO] Retrying request